# php include is not working as expected

Tags: php, include

I am trying to put an `include` into my php page but I keep getting an error. This works fine:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
etc etc
```

But if I put this into an `include`:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('sessiontimer.php');
etc etc
```

with **sessiontimer.php** being:

```
<?php
echo "$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();";
?>
```

and I get the error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''
>   (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in sessiontimer.php on
>   line 2

Is there some rule about including time() or there something else I am missing?

Comment: `echo "$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();";` why do you have that in quotes? that's why you're getting the error and the extra `;` also.

Comment: Since `$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();` works, your include should include just that, no quotes. Yet, I don't quite know what you want to do here.

Comment: As @Fred-ii- states, you need to clarify what you want doing, however I have put two solutions depending on what you want doing, they may or may not help you.

Comment: The rule you're missing is about the syntax for putting variables inside strings.

Comment: I think his confusion is that he thinks that `include` is like accessing the file through the web server: it executes the script remotely and then merges the output into the current script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display that in a string, try the following,

```
<?php

echo "\$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();";

?>
```

**Output**

```
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time()
```

If you wish to set the session variable, try the following,

```
<?php

$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();

?>
```

**Reading Material**

[Variable Parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: If as you think they want to literally output `$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();` as a string, you forgot the `;` and \ ;-) Therefore, `echo "\$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();\";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- added the `;` however it output without the slash at the end too. Good spotting.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Being a bit of a dope, echoing when I didn't need to. Cheers.

Comment: @RGriffiths I for one, still don't know what it is you wanted to do. and posted a comment up there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am setting up a session variable called LAST_ACTIVITY. There will be other stuff going into the include which checks whether there has been any activity on a page or should it destroy the session and log you out. I didn't include that bit (excuse the pun). Now the include works I can just add the include to every page rather than copying the whole thing.